# Replacing all square brackets with curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string `"[[[[[]]]]]"` and I want to convert it in `"{{{{{}}}}}"`. I tried `"[[[[[]]]]]".replace(/[/g,'{').replace(/]/g,'}')` but not luck so far.

Comment: The `[` is a special char in a regex, it must be escaped.

Comment: :P and you were so close

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `[` square bracket has to be escaped.

```js
var string = "[[[[[]]]]]";

console.log(string.replace(/\[/g, '{').replace(/]/g, '}'));
```

Comment: striktly speaking you do not need to escape the `]` but to make it clear I would do it as well

Comment: @Fallenhero Agreed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string = '[[[[]]]]';
console.log(string.replace(/\[/g, "{").replace(/\]/g, "}"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcte0szn/

Comment: you dont need the `\` in `"\}"`