# Syntax error when adding a MultiPolygon geometry

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, geometry, openlayers

I try to add a MultiPolygon geometry in my postgre Database, so i used this SQL statement :

```
'INSERT INTO potentiel_foncier_ccry (nature, geom, nbr_lgmt)  VALUES  ('+ mysql.escape(nature)+', ST_GeomFromText(MULTIPOLYGON((("'+mysql.escape(geom)+')))",2154),"'+ mysql.escape(logement) +'")'
```

but it fails, i have this error:

```
error: syntax error at end of input
```

My geometry look like this : [image]

What's the problem? Thank you in advance

PS: I use Nodejs for coding

Comment: That's a polygon.  Add one more set of `[ ]` for a multipolygon

Comment: I add one more set of () it didn't work, i try with 4 [] the console tell me : syntax error at or near "["

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing that via an OpenLayers application you can convert formats

```
var geom = [[[[101, 201],
              [102, 202],
              [103, 203],
              [101, 201]]]];

var wkt = new ol.format.WKT().writeGeometry(new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(geom));

console.log(wkt);  // 'MULTIPOLYGON(((101 201,102 202,103 203,101 201)))'
```

Assuming the remainder of your SQL is correct you will still need `ST_GeomFromText` and `2154`:

```
var geom1 = [[[[101, 201],
               [102, 202],
               [103, 203],
               [101, 201]]]];

var wkt = new ol.format.WKT().writeGeometry(new ol.geom.MultiPolygon(geom1));

var geom2 = "ST_GeomFromText('" + wkt + "'),2154)"

 'INSERT INTO potentiel_foncier_ccry (nature, geom, nbr_lgmt) VALUES ('+ mysql.escape(nature)+', '+geom2+','+ mysql.escape(logement) +')'
```

Comment: I'm doing this with an OpenLayers Application, i convert like you show me it work but i have an other error  : " syntax error at or near "6379121.466596267"                    
 My sql statement : 'INSERT INTO potentiel_foncier_ccry (nature, geom, nbr_lgmt)  VALUES  ('+ mysql.escape(nature)+', '+geom+','+ mysql.escape(logement) +')'

Comment: Does your new `geom` include `ST_GeomFromText('` and `'),2154)` ?

Answer (score 0):

(still having too little reputation to comment)
looking at the [postgis examples](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html), the MultiPolygon should look something like this (with only round braces):

SELECT ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((-71.1031880899493 42.3152774590236,
-71.1031627617667 42.3152960829043,-71.102923838298 42.3149156848307,
-71.1023097974109 42.3151969047397,-71.1019285062273 42.3147384934248,
-71.102505233663 42.3144722937587,-71.10277487471 42.3141658254797,
-71.103113945163 42.3142739188902,-71.10324876416 42.31402489987,
-71.1033002961013 42.3140393340215,-71.1033488797549 42.3139495090772,
-71.103396240451 42.3138632439557,-71.1041521907712 42.3141153348029,
-71.1041411411543 42.3141545014533,-71.1041287795912 42.3142114839058,
-71.1041188134329 42.3142693656241,-71.1041112482575 42.3143272556118,
-71.1041072845732 42.3143851580048,-71.1041057218871 42.3144430686681,
-71.1041065602059 42.3145009876017,-71.1041097995362 42.3145589148055,
-71.1041166403905 42.3146168544148,-71.1041258822717 42.3146748022936,
-71.1041375307579 42.3147318674446,-71.1041492906949 42.3147711126569,
-71.1041598612795 42.314808571739,-71.1042515013869 42.3151287620809,
-71.1041173835118 42.3150739481917,-71.1040809891419 42.3151344119048,
-71.1040438678912 42.3151191367447,-71.1040194562988 42.3151832057859,
-71.1038734225584 42.3151140942995,-71.1038446938243 42.3151006300338,
-71.1038315271889 42.315094347535,-71.1037393329282 42.315054824985,
-71.1035447555574 42.3152608696313,-71.1033436658644 42.3151648370544,
-71.1032580383161 42.3152269126061,-71.103223066939 42.3152517403219,
-71.1031880899493 42.3152774590236)),
((-71.1043632495873 42.315113108546,-71.1043583974082 42.3151211109857,
-71.1043443253471 42.3150676015829,-71.1043850704575 42.3150793250568,-71.1043632495873 42.315113108546)))',4326);

Are you sure that mysql.escape(geom) creates this syntax?

Comment: Mysql.escape don't create this syntax,it escape special characters.I don't know a function to create this syntax , so that's why i specified "(((" at the beginning and ")))" at the end

Comment: maybe there is a better way, but if you got your geometry as string (e.g. as geojson), you can replace your brackets with the other kind of brackets, maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228387/replacing-all-square-brackets-with-curly-brackets

Comment: Thanks you for your help but i have an error : syntax error at or near "6378801.386540322"